# How to dynamically change colour of errorstyle in textformfield based on validator?

Tags: flutter, dart, textformfield

I have a `TextFormField` that checks if the input meets a set of requirements using validator. If the input does not meet a specific requirement an error text in *red* will inform the user accordingly. I want to return a text in *green* ("Secure password") if the password meets all of the requirements.

```
class RegForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegFormState createState() => _RegFormState();
}

class _RegFormState extends State<RegForm> {
  Color errorClr = Colors.red;
  final String checkAll =
                r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$';
  final String checkLetters = r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])';
  final String checkNumbers = r'^(?=.*?[0-9])';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TextFormField(
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter a valid password';
          } else {
            if (value.length < 8)
              return 'Password has to be 8 characters or more!';
            else if (!RegExp(checkLetters).hasMatch(value))
              return 'Password has to contain Uppercase and Lowercase letters!';
            else if (!RegExp(checkNumbers).hasMatch(value))
              return 'Password has to contain numbers!';
            else if (RegExp(checkAll).hasMatch(value)) {
              errorClr = Colors.green;
              return 'Very secure password!';
            }
          }
          errorClr = Colors.green;
          return 'Secure password!';
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          errorStyle: TextStyle(
            color: errorClr,
          ),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          hintText:
              'Password must be at least 8 characters long, contains numbers and both upper and lowercase letters',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code above will not return the "Secure password" text in green and I figured its because validator doesn't rebuild the widget, thus the `errorStyle` doesn't update. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: In your validator function, return null in case of success. This will take care of the UI for you. From the docs: "Returns an error string to display if the input is invalid, or null otherwise". 

If you want to rebuild the widget you can call setState from the onChanged method of TextFormField: onChanged: (value) => setState(() { })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `setState()` from whithin the validator function, which is what you need to change the `errorClr` or the success text. Also the validator function needs to return `null` to indicate that the validation passes; so you cant simply return *Secure password!*.

What do you think about using `helperText` to output the success message.

> If non-null, the text is displayed below the InputDecorator.child, in the same location as errorText. If a non-null errorText value is specified then the helper text is not shown.

Define a new variable that indicates if the password is valid (default: false):

```
bool validPassword = false;
```

Use `onChanged` to check for the valid password:

```
onChanged: (String value) {
  if (RegExp(checkAll).hasMatch(value))
    setState(() {
      validPassword = true;
    });
  },
```

Add `helperText` and `helperStyle` to your `InputDecoration`:

```
 helperText: validPassword ? 'Secure Password' : null,
 helperStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
```

Complete Example:

```
class _RegFormState extends State<RegForm> {
  final String checkAll = r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$';
  final String checkSpecial = r'^(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~])';
  final String checkLetters = r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])';
  final String checkNumbers = r'^(?=.*?[0-9])';

  bool validPassword = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TextFormField(
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty || value.trim().length < 8) // use trim() for the whitrespaces
              return 'Password has to be 8 characters or more!';

            if (!RegExp(checkLetters).hasMatch(value))
              return 'Password has to contain Uppercase and Lowercase letters!';

            if (!RegExp(checkNumbers).hasMatch(value))
              return 'Password has to contain numbers!';

            if (!RegExp(checkSpecial).hasMatch(value))
              return 'Password has to contain a special character!';

            return null; // to indicate a success
         },
         onChanged: (String value) {
           if (RegExp(checkAll).hasMatch(value))
             setState(() {
               validPassword = true;
             });
           },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          helperText: validPassword ? 'Secure Password' : null,
          helperStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
          hintText:
          'Password must be at least 8 characters long, contains numbers and both upper and lowercase letters',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
         ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```